# I am getting this error: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. on a Experience cloud site

Tags: permissions, customer-community, permission-sets, experience-cloud, organization-wide

I have an Experience cloud site, and a 'Community Plus User' is trying to update a record, I get this error message when he clicks on the standard 'Edit' button:

> **Looks like there's a problem.**
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation
> you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your
> administrator if access is necessary.

The OWS for that object are External: Public Read Only. I gave edit access to that community user via a Permission Set Group that includes a Permission Set, that have 'Read and Edit access to the object.

All the object fields have **Read and Edit Access** associated to this Permission Set.

When I added this Permission Set Group to the user, the Edit button became visible on the Page Layout. Which confirms that the user does have the right assignment. However when he clicks on the 'Edit' button, the error pops-up. What could I be missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: does user have edit access to any required lookup fields (and their parent objects) on `Core Reports`?

Comment: @cropredy Is does have edit access to the Account object and related record. The other lookup is the User. It does have read access to the object and record. I dont understand what else I could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, you have given edit access to the object, but not Modify all access, possibly this record is still read-only(after adding permission set) to the user trying to edit the same.
So navigate to the record in Salesforce internal and check for record edit access for this end user.

Comment: I cant give Modify All access because it is a Community Plus user and the license is not compatible with the All access rights.